# Can I inscribe or inset a holy symbol into my longbow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric

In the Player's Handbook, the holy symbols of the gods are detailed.  The symbol of Corellon Larethian is a crescent moon.  Can I take some of my chalk, and draw (reverently, of course) a crescent moon symbol on my longbow and thus be wielding a Holy Symbol of Corellon when I wield said bow?  In previous editions, the holy symbol would have to be consecrated but is this still true in 3.5?  If the sacred application of chalk is insufficient, could I inset my silver holy symbol into my longbow's grip and be wielding a holy symbol at the same time as the bow?  If not, why?

Comment: Well, there is the Larethian Protector (Arms and Equipment Guide, P.112) that looks like the symbol of Corellon, but it's not actually a holy symbol. Still pretty spiffy for an Elven Cleric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there are basically two related-but-not-quite-the-same things referred to as a *holy symbol*. There is the icon itself (Corellon’s crescent moon, Silver Flame’s, well, silver flame, and so on), and then there is the object known as a *holy symbol*, which has the shape of the icon. The rules refer to each of these rather interchangeably, as English and indeed most languages are wont to do, but as Magritte pointed out, [this is not a pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images).

The divine focus requirement of certain cleric spells, as well as for turn or rebuke undead, those rely on the *holy symbol* **item**, not merely the icon. Whether this is because the item is consecrated or whatever else is not defined, but the fact remains that the item itself is a requirement. Certain other items may substitute (most notably, an option for a shield allows it to be used as a replacement for the *holy symbol* item), but any mere representation of the icon does not suffice as a *holy sumbol* item. Such an icon may be pious, may declare a thing as belonging to your god, but it is, apparently, insufficient to channel your god’s power.

Answer (score 7):

## An engraving or illustration of a deity's emblem isn't a [holy symbol](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#holySymbolSilverorWooden)

The [holy symbol](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#holySymbolSilverorWooden) needed [to turn or rebuke undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/cleric.htm#turnorRebukeUndead) and that's mandated as the [divine focus](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#components) necessary for casting some cleric and paladin spells has a cost (and, in some cases, weight). As a distinct and quantified object in the rules, manufacturing one's own holy symbol requires the appropriate [Craft](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/craft.htm) skill, the DM determining the DC of the Craft skill check.

Freely creating one's own homemade holy symbols is no more allowed than freely creating one's own homemade swords.

### Holy symbol alternatives

*Dungeonscape* in the section Weapon and Armor Modification presents the armor and shield modification sanctified which says that

> This modification makes the armor [or shield] a legitimate divine focus for divine spellcasters of that faith. (34)

Further, *Faiths of Eberron* presents the feat Worldly Focus, which says that

> You can cast cleric spells without the need of a divine focus. (148)

The feat's prerequisite is Eberron-specific, and the cleric must still present his holy (or unholy) symbol to turn (or rebuke) undead.